# Asp.net Web API Post List<t> Not Getting Inside Method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am running into a problem where I can't seem to pass this data properly from jquery to the web api.

**Here is my javascript code:**

```
var chartRequestParams = [
     { QueueMode: "Investigations", DataMode: "items_completed" },
     { QueueMode: "Investigations", DataMode: "items_completed_avg_age" },
     { QueueMode: "Investigations", DataMode: "active_items" }
];

$.post('/api/dashboard/GetActiveAgeChart', chartRequestParams, function (data) {  });
```

**Here is my Web API Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public List<HighChartsResponse> GetActiveAgeChart(List<ChartRequestParam> chartRequestParams)
{ .....continued....
```

*It's not even making it into the above method*

**Here is my "model"**

```
public class ChartRequestParam
{
  public ChartRequestParam()
  {
    this.QueueMode = string.Empty;
    this.DataMode = string.Empty;
  }

  public string QueueMode { get; set; }
  public string DataMode { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried soooo many variations of this code with no success. Basically I'm just trying to post a List to the web API method.

I receive a 500 server error, and it if i set a breakpoint inside the "GetActiveAgeChart" method it doesn't even hit it.

Comment: Just a blind shot, but have you tried setting the webapi method parameter as an array, instead of a list? (and/or use `[ModelBinder]` on the parameter)

Comment: Just tried both - trying it just as an array with no modelbinder it didn't hit the method, trying it as an array with modelbinder it hit the method but the array was empty.

Comment: Modelbinder with a List, maybe? (again, just blind shooting)

Comment: Yea tried that too - haha - i've tried SO MANY variations, just no go =(

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume your controller is named `DashboardController`. If so, you will need to post to `/api/dashboard` without the action method in the URI. Web API does support RPC-style but it is not probably important for this.

Second, you will need to stringify the payload, something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/dashboard', type: 'POST', contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(chartRequestParams)
});
```

This will post the request message as JSON. If you prefer it to be www-form-urlencoded, you will need to read http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/177.

Comment: Hi Badri, you are correct, the controller is DashboardController. I've tried your suggestions but they did not work.

Comment: @Loren What was the error? It made it inside your controller's method? Have you tried to look into your request's content (what is actually getting posted)?

Comment: Did you try `$.post('/api/dashboard', { '': chartRequestParams }, function (data) { });`? With `/api/dashboard`, it should be going inside your action method.

Comment: It did not make it inside my controller method, the error is a 500 error

Comment: should it be { '': JSON.stringy(chartRequestParams) } ?

Comment: Also - not using an action in the url returns 404